# What aircraft design elements contribute the most to sustained flight?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, cg

If I wanted to design an aircraft for autonomous operation and maximum endurance, what design philosophies provide the greatest benefit?  I'm imagining a powered glider.  Does not have to be highly maneuverable.

I'm interested in relative proportions, wingspan, length, center of gravity, center of pressure, wing placement, dihedral/anhedral, engine placement, fuel type, etc.

- Is there a "sweet spot" for center of gravity relative to center of lift so as to maximize stability?
- Since it will be mostly autonomous (computer-controlled), can I design for less inherent stability?
- What engines/fuel types are the most efficient?

Comment: What kind of an aircraft are you thinking of? In what ways might it be similar to and different from a [Reaper](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQ-9_Reaper), say?

Comment: the reaper is a good starting point, at least in terms of using it as an example for *why* the design looks like it does.  i was thinking something more in the tactical realm, perhaps no bigger than 15-20' wingspan, or something hobbyists could put together on the weekend.

Comment: A balloon :-). ${}$

Comment: What exactly is a powered glider? Do you mean a [motor glider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_glider) that has an engine for take-off only?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick there are a number of different kinds of motor gliders: self-launching (instead of a tow or winch), sustaining (in case you fail to find lift), and touring (can operate like an airplane).

Comment: The best approach you can use is to select a similar aircraft and start from that design adapting to yours. From what you say maybe the Predator UAV is your best option, taking that design just iterate the design by removing military systems. Scale it back to the payload you need. Copy/Paste is usually the best option generally.

Comment: Don't use a configuration that was selected to be transported in a torpedo tube and then made to behave the hard way. It will be better to start with something that was designed to fly stable all by itself.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick it could be, only the motor would be left on all or most of the time instead of switched off/stowed at altitude.  but i'm also open to alternative technologies to produce thrust, so i left it as simply "powered".

Answer (score 2):

Natural stability would be highest on the list for me. Look at free flying model airplanes for inspiration. They have their own characteristics:

- Very low wing loading for minimum sink speed
- High natural stability, and consequently a very narrow speed range
- High aspect ratio wing, thin airfoil with high camber
- Extremely short fuselage ahead of the wing (no payload to carry)
- Extreme fuselage length aft of the wing which provides ample aerodynamic damping
- Strong dihedral of the outer wing.

This in combination means that your control software can be very simple. Relaxed stability will require many sensors and built-in redundancy, and the more parts you need to add, the more possibilities of failures you will end up with. In contrast to that, the laws of physics never fail, use them to your advantage. See below for an example which I copied from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_flight_(model_aircraft)) on free flight models:

[image]

For airfols, c.g. location and all other details I recommend to look at [several free plans](http://freeflight.org/community/links.htm) until you see a common pattern.

Regarding the type of fuel: Depends how noisy and messy you tolerate the engine to be; some people will only fly electric while others are happy with two-stroke engines.